# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when using jsoup.connect(String url).get() - Not on android

Tags: java, jsoup

My friend and I were recently bored, so I created a program that, using Jsoup, selects a random movie off of the Redbox website for us to watch. This program worked fine within my IDE (Eclipse Luna) but when I exported it, I got the following error upon running:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities$EscapeMode.<clinit>(Entities.java:20)
        at org.jsoup.nodes.Document$OutputSettings.<init>(Document.java:221)
        at org.jsoup.nodes.Document.<init>(Document.java:18)
        at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.initialiseParse(TreeBuilder.java:27)
        at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.parse(TreeBuilder.java:40)
        at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.parse(HtmlTreeBuilder.java:54)
        at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parseInput(Parser.java:30)
        at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseByteData(DataUtil.java:120)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:51
7)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:168)
        at RedboxRoulette.InfoGrabber.main(InfoGrabber.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
        at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.loadEntities(Entities.java:151)
        at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.<clinit>(Entities.java:135)
        ... 11 more
```

The Program:

```
public class InfoGrabber {
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException{
    String url = "http://www.redbox.com/movies/";
    System.out.println("Loading redbox.com...");

    ArrayList<String> movieList = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Gets website using Jsoup
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    //Finds the movies
    Elements movies = doc.select(".box-wrapper");

    //Adds them to a list
    for (Element movie : movies) {
        String name = movie.attr("name");
        movieList.add(name);
    }

    //Picks a random movie
    int movieNumber = (int) (Math.random()*movieList.size());
    String finalMovie = movieList.get(movieNumber);
    System.out.println("Movie: " + finalMovie);
 }

}
```

I am very much a beginner at Jsoup and I am also still learning java however looking at all of the tutorials out there this seems to be the way things should work.

I have tried exporting it as a runnable jar file using the three different export options in eclipse however every one provides the same result. I have also tried to create the jar file manually but that, like the jar file eclipse made, throws the error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Update:
Upon mirroring the process found in the comments , I now get this error:

```
Missing attributes for JarRsrcLoader in Manifest (Rsrc-Main-Class, Rsrc-Class-Path)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:46)
```

The Manifest file that eclipse creates:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ jsoup-1.7.3.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: RedboxRoulette.InfoGrabber
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `Eclipse Kepler`.
I've made a new project with one class. I pasted your code.
I icluded `jsoup-1.7.3.jar` by right clicking the project
Select `Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries(tab)->Add External JARs`

I exported the jar by right clicking the project
Select `Export->Runnable JAR File->Select 'Package required libraries into generated JAR'.`

Open cmd go to the jar's location and execute

```
java -jar <name of the jar>
```

and it works fine.

For the java command of course you the set the environment variables first.

Comment: This process now gives me a new error. I must have been doing something wrong before and thanks for showing me the right process however I now get a new error (Now added to the original post). The only thing that varies between the programs we created (and I have checked this) is the eclipse version which I can't see making too big of a difference.